# "SessionId doesn't exist" error when starting Selenium server

Tags: selenium

I'm raising a Selnium-server (the jar), and getting this exception without trying to talk to the server. What can be the cause? The errors keep coming in once every 2 seconds. Could this be some leftover from a previous Selenium run?

```
C:\Foo>java -jar ..\..\..\..\lib\Selenium\selenium-server.jar
14:53:30.141 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 14.2-b01
14:53:30.142 INFO - OS: Windows Server 2008 6.1 amd64
14:53:30.149 INFO - v1.0.1 [2696], with Core v@VERSION@ [@REVISION@]
14:53:30.209 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
14:53:30.210 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
14:53:30.211 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
14:53:30.211 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
14:53:30.217 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
14:53:30.218 INFO - Started org.mortbay.jetty.Server@2747ee05
14:53:31.729 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
14:53:31.735 WARN - POST /selenium-server/driver/?seleniumStart=true&localFrameAddress=top&seleniumWindowName=
&uniqueId=sel_27224&sessionId=1f2385b8bae24f6fb79816753de7cd69&counterToMakeURsUniqueAndSoStopPageCachingInThe
Browser=1255006411692&sequenceNumber=268 HTTP/1.1
java.lang.RuntimeException: sessionId 1f2385b8bae24f6fb79816753de7cd69 doesn't exist; perhaps this session was
 already stopped?
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.getQueueSet(FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.java:218
)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handleBrowserResponse(SeleniumDriverResour
ceHandler.java:159)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handle(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:
127)
        at org.mortbay.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
        at org.mortbay.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
        at org.mortbay.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
        at org.mortbay.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
        at org.mortbay.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
        at org.mortbay.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:245)
        at org.mortbay.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
        at org.mortbay.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any tests running when you start the server? You could look at any incoming network traffic to port 4444 to find out what's generating the requests. If you can't find who/what is sending the requests you could change the port to something other than 4444 when you start the server.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dave, it must be some application which is trying to connect to port 4444. Just change the port number and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and it appeared an mshta.exe process was hanging on the test server. It also consumed an absurd amount of memory (600MB), slowing down the entire server.

Try turning the server off and on again.